# "прицепить" лупу к поиску

Tags: html, css, search, position

Есть поле ввода типа `search`, в котором по дизайну нужно держать лупу в правой части. На данный момент так и есть - но они наложены друг на друга, и соответственно не связаны.

В случае уменьшения ширины поля `search`, лупа остается как-бы сама по себе.

Каким образом связать картинку и поле ввода?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.search-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 435px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 365px;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.search {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 32px;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  /* max-width: 435px; */
}

.search__magnifier {
  background-image: url(../images/search_magnifier.png);
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: no-repeat;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap_content">
    <span id="logo">Aditii</span>

    <div class="search-wrapper">

      <input class="search" type="text">
      <img class="search__magnifier" src="images/search_magnifier.png">

    </div>

    <div class="purchase">
      <img class="purchase__basket" src="images/basket_icon.png" alt="Корзина">
      <span class="purchase__amount">300$</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: такой вариант подойдет? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ww5nvjzg/

Comment: @soledar10 да, оформите как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 435px;
    height: 32px;
    left: 365px;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.search {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    border-color: #e1e1e1;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    /* max-width: 435px; */
    background: url('http://heartlandpreciousmetals.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-dual-picture-display/images/zoom-icon.png?84409a') no-repeat 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-wrapper">
    <input class="search" type="text">    
</form>
```

или так

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 435px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.search {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 32px;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.search-submit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.search-submit>img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-wrapper">
  <input class="search" type="text" required>
  <button class="search-submit" type="submit">
        <img src="http://heartlandpreciousmetals.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-dual-picture-display/images/zoom-icon.png?84409a" alt="">
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: стоит добавить `box-sizing: border-box;` для `.search`